# get the post types from the costum type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have displayed all the post types in one page but my code is not end user supported.
I mean i want when user add a custom type using custom type post plugin, the post type should add automatically in my code. My code now as bellow.

```
    $post_types = array('a', 'b','c','d','e');//post type names
    foreach( $post_types as $post_type) {

    // The Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
     'post_type' => $post_type,
     'orderby' => 'post_date',
     'order' => 'DESC',
     'showposts' => 1,
    ));
```

i want the variable $post_types should be added automatically when user add a custom post type.

Comment: You can set `'post_type' => 'any'`, but that would include attachments as well. Otherwise look into using [Function Reference/get post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types).

Comment: i dont want to display f and g type.

Comment: Isn't "Output a list of all public custom post types" - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types#Output_a_list_of_all_public_custom_post_types going to work for you?